# HSQLDB - Changing the specific name of a procedure

Tags: hsqldb

I created some procedures without providing a specific name and I would like to know if there is a way to change the automatically generated specific name.

Without having to drop and create the procedures again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible in version 2.4.1 with an SQL statement. You can edit the .script file of the database and change the name.

Support for `ALTER SPECIFIC ROUTINE <name> RENAME TO <new name>` will be added to version 2.5.0.